# Operators overloading in generated class based on the methods of base class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, operator-overloading, traits

The question is devoted to an implementation of some helper class `Traits` for an automatic generation of some sorts of second-order functions.

For example there are two different objects

```
//some realization of matrix
class MatrixA{
  ...
};

//totally different realization with different
//public members, different constructors etc.
class MatrixB{
  ...
};
```

and I want to use these two functionally the same objects in some highly abstract code (e.g. in matrix diagonalisation). Abstract means here that we don't need to know nothing about a particular realization of matrix object. Instead of it we should just define some standard operations such as sum of matrices, multiplication on vector etc.

In order to do it I use some traits interface

```
//traits
//template interface for matrix algebra
template<typename MatrixType>
class TemplateAlgebra{
  typedef MatrixType matrix_t;
public:
  virtual matrix_t matrix_add(const matrix_t& m1,
                              const matrix_t& m2) const=0;
};

//template traits class
template<typename MatrixType, typename MatrixAlgebra>
class TemplateTraits{
public:
  typedef MatrixType matrix_t;
  typedef MatrixAlgebra matrix_algebra_t;
};
```

where I defined some template operations (e.g. summation here).

Then by defining a particular realization for every matrix type

```
//overriding of concrete matrix algebra for MatrixA type
class AlgebraA:
public TemplateAlgebra<MatrixA>{
public:
  MatrixA matrix_add(const MatrixA& m1,
                     const MatrixA& m2) const override{
    //here we use some operations from MatrixA class
  }
};

//and create a traits for MatrixA
typedef TemplateTraits<MatrixA,AlgebraA> ATraits;
```

I abstracted an individual properties of every matrix type in some general interface.

All of these work fine.

Problems start when I trying to generate some additional functions from knowledge of a general ones.

```
//here the place with errors
//the goal of this class is to generate some second-order functions
//from knowledge of some basic functions which defined in traits
template<typename Traits>
class AutoGenerator:
public Traits::matrix_algebra_t{
  typedef typename Traits::matrix_t matrix_t;
  typedef typename Traits::matrix_algebra_t matrix_algebra_t;
public:
  AutoGenerator(){}

  //some member function works perfectly
  void sum(const matrix_t& m1, const matrix_t& m2){
    matrix_algebra_t::matrix_add(m1,m2);//works fine
  }

  //however there is a problem with friend declaration! 
  template<typename T=Traits>
  friend matrix_t operator+(const matrix_t& m1, const matrix_t& m2){
    matrix_algebra_t::matrix_add(m1,m2);//doen't work
  }
};
```

In particular you can see that there is a problem with generation of some operators. When I compile it I have an error: `error: cannot call member function "...::matrix_add" without object`.

I very well know why this error occur, so please don't explain to me that I try to call non static member without a class object. I'm just deadlocked with this probably simple question because I work with it a lot of time and I don't see a solution.

So, finally, the question is "How by using some template traits class is it possible to overload an operators?". In particular `+` operator.

Sorry for this a really long explanation I just wanted to avoid some "stupid" answers in kind off "Just add it in the particular matrix class". I don't want to modify particular classes (by using an external libs for matrix I even haven't access to it). And thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why are you using virtual functions anyway? Since the whole thing appears to be template-based, why not get rid of objects altogether and use static member functions in `TemplateAlgebra`? `AlberaA` would then be a *specialisation* of `TemplateAlgebra` instead of a class derived from it.

Comment: Probably I'm wrong but by using static functions in such a way the overloaded operator will be the same in the whole code. I didn't mention in explanation that I want to use a different generators classes in different parts of code. It is necessary because I use a few external libs which required a different results of overloaded operators (for example in boost::odeint one result, in the lib for diagonalisation another). So that's the reason why an implementation of static functions is not a suitable for my case.

Answer (score 0):

It appears your algebra class holds no data. In such case, it should be trivial to create an on-demand instance of it:

```
template<typename T=Traits>
friend matrix_t operator+(const matrix_t& m1, const matrix_t& m2){
  matrix_algebra_t().matrix_add(m1,m2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the difference. Your `void sum(const matrix_t& m1, const matrix_t& m2)` is a member of `AutoGenerator`, which derives from `matrix_algebra_t`, so calling `matrix_algebra_t::matrix_add(...)` effectively calls the function from the base class.

Your `template<typename T=Traits>
  friend matrix_t operator+(const matrix_t& m1, const matrix_t& m2)`, however, is not a member of `AutoGenerator`, so to be able to call `matrix_algebra_t::matrix_add(...)` in it, `matrix_add()` should be a static function of `matrix_algebra_t`. You will need to create an object of `matrix_algebra_t`, and call the function on it:

```
matrix_algebra_t().matrix_add(m1,m2);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Now it works! How the creation of object during an every calling of operator will affect on performance? Or the compiler should optimize it?

Comment: @QuantumNik, hard to say. If can make that `matrix_algebra` instance `static` if you care about that (assuming that calling `matrix_add` multiple times on the same instance does not mess it's state).